# Data Transformation in Microsoft Jet Database Engine

Tags: ms-access

What query should use, If I have a dataset that I want to transform

```
From | To | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
123 130 AB  DE  EF
131 140 WS  ED  RF
141 145 GT  HY  JU
```

and I want to print the following data set in Microsoft Jet database engine or MS Access.

```
ID | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
123 AB  DE  EF
124 AB  DE  EF
125 AB  DE  EF
126 AB  DE  EF
127 AB  DE  EF
128 AB  DE  EF
129 AB  DE  EF
130 AB  DE  EF
131 WS  ED  RF
132 WS  ED  RF
133 WS  ED  RF
134 WS  ED  RF
135 WS  ED  RF
136 WS  ED  RF
137 WS  ED  RF
138 WS  ED  RF
139 WS  ED  RF
140 WS  ED  RF
141 GT  HY  JU
142 GT  HY  JU
143 GT  HY  JU
144 GT  HY  JU
145 GT  HY  JU
```

Comment: What database engine are you using MS Access or SQL Server? Vast difference between them.

Comment: I am using MS Access at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This works on SQL- Server but not sure how you can use this technique when using access.

```
create table #t (F_Val int, 
    To_Val int, 
    Val1 varchar(5), 
    Val2 varchar(5), 
    Val3 varchar(5)
)

insert into #t values
(123, 130, 'AB', 'DE', 'EF'),
(131, 140, 'WS', 'ED', 'RF'),
(141, 145, 'GT', 'HY', 'JU')

;with ct as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY object_id) as RN
    from sys.objects
)
select RN, #t.Val1, #t.Val2, #t.Val3
from ct
    inner join #t on ct.RN between #t.F_Val and #t.To_Val
```

juts note that number of sys.objects are limited in database so this will not work for bigger range but the idea is that.

Answer (score 0):

Create and save a query, qdxFactor, with this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
    Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca;
```

Then create a Cartesian query:

```
Select
    [From] + Factor As ID,
    Val1,
    Val2,
    Val3
From
    YourTable,
    qdxFactor
Where
    [From] + Factor <= [To]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your post - your data set has 2 dates for the date range; From and To. You seek to create records for all the dates in the date range.

A table join method is the easiest - but one must have a new table that holds all possible values of the ID field.  So in the example you post you need a table with a single column, ID, that has 22 records from 123 to 145.  But I imagine in real life your data set is probably much larger - which is okay just more difficult sometimes to create.  Let's call this the ID Table.

In your select query, you join ID Table to Table 1 with the join clause SQL syntax of: 
[Table 1].[From] >= [ID Table].[ID] AND [Table 1].[To] <= [ID Table].[ID].

If your ID range is very large to essentially infinite - then one would need a different approach that increments up the ID value on the fly.  This can be slow.  A more efficient variation could be to create the needed ID Table on the fly just for the range set needed at the time of the query.